# restore kubelet.conf via foremost or scalpel

Tags: linux, kubernetes, undelete

/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf on was deleted.
may be anyone has

/etc/foremost.conf format for conf file to restore

or is it possible to regenerate this config without cluster init
ort may be some was used scalpel for such restorations

Comment: How did you start your cluster? Did you consider recreating the node?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing you can do is to recreate the node.

But if you really don't want to recreate it, [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) provides great explaination how to generate this file by hand.

Check out:

- [Generating kubelet client certificates](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#the-kubelet-client-certificates)
- [Generating kubelet config files](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/05-kubernetes-configuration-files.md#the-kubelet-kubernetes-configuration-file)

Comment: This kubelet conf was deletedon master. And it still up and running

Answer (score 0):

As for restoring "kubelet.conf" file option.

If you need to add custom type files' configuration to foremost, just remember that admin kubeconfig file does not differ from other `kubeconfig` files. Just look at existing one from one of your worker nodes.

Reconstructing "kubelet.conf" from scratch options:

- **Option A**

Running following command with kubeadm* ** will help to re-create a new kubeconfig file dedicated for control plane node

```
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig kubelet --kubeconfig-dir=/tmp/new/
```

*it stores a new kubeconfig `kubelet.conf` file in `/tmp/new/` dir instead default location `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`
** it's kind of workaround, and gives actually newly generated client certificate for control plane node

- **Option B**

Proper way of getting back control plane's credentials is through CSR API, quoting after official documentation:

> After your control plane is up, you should request all kubelet
> credentials from the CSR API

How to achieve it is documented in admin section of K8S doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/#kubelet-configuration):